# How to decode the H.264 video stream received from parcelfiledescriptor

Tags: android, sockets, video-streaming, decode, video-capture

I'm creating an Android application of live video streaming between two android phone. I've already established a socket connection between these devices. I'm capturing video in one device and send the stream to other device but currently I just want to save in the receiver side mobile device and save it. I'm recording using `MediaRecorder` in one device , so to stream to the receiver I,m using `parcelfiledescriptor` object by setting the data

**Client side code**

```
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
```

**Receiver side code**

```
  pfd= ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(s);
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor()); 
  DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);  
  OutputStream newDatabase = new FileOutputStream(file);
  int available=in.available();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[available];
  int length;


                while((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    newDatabase.write(buffer, 0, length);

                }
                newDatabase.close();
```

The video file is being created on the receiver side mobile, but it's not able to receive any bytes. So Do I've to decode the coming stream on the receiver side since the video stream sent is encoded while recording. So how can I decode the stream that is received ? I found some solution like MediaExtractor and MediaCodec...but will this work with live video capturing and moreover I'm testing on `android version 2.3.6 GingerBread`
Is it possible to decode the video stream from `MediaCodec` for version 2.3.6 or some other method is available ?

Comment: Hi Divya Did u get solution,I'm too facing same problem plz let me know if u have found solutions

Comment: Hiiii Dipu as replied to David i was able to save but still have many issues...please check my comment for David's reply

Answer (score 2):

> The video file is being created on the receiver side mobile, but it's not able to receive any bytes.

If I understand you right, you are getting no data from the socket. That is a separate problem, which has nothing to do with the video format, decoding or encoding.

To debug your sockets, it may be helpful to use a separate application which just dumps the recieved data. Once the data looks fine, you can go to the next step - decoding the video.

---

Second part of the problem is the video format. You are using mp4, which is not usable for streaming. [Here is more info about the format structure.](http://hello-qd.blogspot.it/2013/05/how-to-process-mediarecorder-frames.html) You can use mp4 to record a video into a local file and then transfer the whole file over socket somewhere, but true realtime streaming cannot be done because of the non-seekable nature of the socket (as described in the linked article). There is a block of metadata at the beginning of the file, which acts as a "table of contents" and without it, the previous data are just junk. The problem is, you can assemble a "table of contents" only after you got all the contents. But at that moment, the data was already sent through the socket and you cannot insert anything at its beginning.

There are few walkarounds, but that's just for your future research and I haven't used them yet.

The most intuitive way would be to switch from mp4 to mpeg-ts, a container designed for streaming. Take a look at a hidden constant in `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat` with value 8.

Another option is to pack the raw H.264 data into RTP/RTCP packets, which is again a protocol designed for streaming. Also your application would be able to stream to any device that support this protocol (for example a PC running VLC). To further reasearch, take a look at [Spydroid IP camera](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/), which does exactly the thing.

Comment: Hiiii David...I was able to save the file on the other device by parcelfiledescriptor object...means i changed the code in the receiving side..means i set a condition to write the file until it is connected to socket to write it on the server side mobile..but one more problem is again the saved video on server side am not able to play the file in my default android media player...but it can be played by other media player like MXPlayer on mobile which is installed and on pc through vlc player...so can u suggest me how to decode the video and play..what is the approach

Comment: And also now i need it as live video streaming as and when am recording from one device i need to play it on other device..I created a MediaPlayer object on the server side and to mediaPlayer.setDataSource(pfd.getFileDescriptor()); it is unable to play the video...it gives an exception "Unable to create a mediaPlayer"... so please can you give some ideo how to resolve this and to play since in my android application i can only create default mediaplayer object which is not supporting to play...how to proceed....

Comment: and also you have mentioned Once the data looks fine, you can go to the next step - decoding the video...so how to do

Comment: I suggested you try to send a regular file first, to see if it comes out ok. Then you move to video content. But again, you won't be able to simply stream by writing into a file/socket and pulling data back at the other end.

Comment: Hiii I am able to send a regular file...that is already done before....this issue only am facing...means also i got to know that i cant play the stream sent by parcelfiledescriptor object directly which am going to stream... since it will have headers and some information related to video missing....so how to resolve this issue means i need to take that stream and play the video

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment, but my best suggestion would be to stop reinventing wheel and take a look at Spydroid or some similar project.

Comment: Ya sorry my comment was not in proper manner..ya in Spydroid project they are using there own classess to create rtp packets and sending..is it that i also need to implement all those classes for the video to stream online..or any other inbuilt mechanism is there to receive the stream and play the video stream

Comment: My previous comment was regarding to the question i have asked means need to stream the video from client side as i hav asked  mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor()); i have set in client side code..and i have been able to recieve the stream and save it as a file on the other android device..but am not able to play that file(which is saved on the other device)..in the android default mediaplayer but can play in other 3rd party mediaplayer...so how to play the stream (online)..is there any mechanism to play it.. or as you told i need to implement as by refering Spydroid only??

Comment: I'd say there should already be an app in the store, capable of playing video from network stream. I wouldn't dare decoding the stream myself.